# Java for loop/jvm broken?!? Increment operator inside loop does not increment after 1

Tags: java, jvm

Striking the weirdest bit of code in the debugger and runtime. I have an ArrayList populated with 60 objects. When I iterate over this list and check the cards inside for uniqueness, the increment operator does not seem to work?!?

This is my code that checks:

```
public boolean isPresentOnce(PlayingCard cardToCheck) {
    int foundTimes = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<playingCards.size();i++) {
        if (playingCards.get(i).equals(cardToCheck)) {
            foundTimes++;
            System.out.println("Found the card:"+foundTimes+":"+i);
        }
    }
    return foundTimes == 1;
}
```

I get this output:

```
Found the card:1:0
Found the card:1:1
Found the card:1:2
Found the card:1:3
<<SNIP>>
Found the card:1:56
Found the card:1:57
Found the card:1:58
Found the card:1:59
```

**Why does my counter not get incremented over 1?**

I tried cleaning my workspace, tried doing a maven clean install, alternating the code by using +=1. and by using a little more complex double if statement. Nothing seems to work, this corner of the code somehow seems to be broken. When using the double if statement, a return statement simply does not exit the method.

Some more side information:

Using IntelliJ 13.1.5 with JRE 1.6.0_65 64bits with HotSpot on a MacBook Pro running 10.9.5.

Population looks like this:

```
private ArrayList<PlayingCard> generateCards() {
    ArrayList<PlayingCard> cards = new ArrayList<PlayingCard>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        PlayingCard playingCard = new PlayingCard();
        List<CardImage> images = new ArrayList<CardImage>();
        images.add(new CardImage(TokenColor.Blue, TokenType.Book));
        images.add(new CardImage(TokenColor.Gray, TokenType.Chair));
        playingCard.addImages(images);
        cards.add(playingCard);
    }
    return cards;
}
```

Apologies for the crappy code, this is a hobby project ;-)

Comment: You need to share your PlayingCard class. Have you overridden equals over there ?

Comment: Is this output from single call to `isPresentOnce` method?

Comment: Is this the verbatim code, you execute? I seriously doubt that. Do you possibly have switched the for statement and the declaration of  foundTimes?

Comment: I have the code on Github: https://github.com/sunsear/VlotteGeesten. The PlayingCard class is at: https://github.com/sunsear/VlotteGeesten/blob/master/game-engine/src/main/java/eu/van_dijken/vlottegeesten/engine/PlayingCard.java It does not implement equals or hashcode so this code shouldn't even enter the System.out.println, but it does!

Comment: I guess each card is only once in your deck?

Comment: Everything is tangled here, you're spot on @Antoniossss. This is the output from 60 calls, still confused though. It is called from https://github.com/sunsear/VlotteGeesten/blob/master/game-engine/src/test/java/eu/van_dijken/vlottegeesten/steps/GameStepDefinitions.java#L58

Comment: Your response to Antoniossss has the answer: if this output is the result of 60 invocations of isPresentOnce, the deck contains 60 unique cards and the method is being invoked on each card instance then the method is working normally.  Definitely not a JVM bug.

Comment: Quite right @Nick, I'm an idiot :-D I was looking in completely the wrong spot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So erm if I understand you correctly, you want to check if every card is only once in your deck? Right? And now you are confused about the output?

So the output is e.g:

```
Found the card:1:2
```

Which means that it found the card at position 2!, incremented the counter by one and therefore you get the output.

The first 1 is the times the card has been found and 2 is the position in the List. So everything is fine!

Comment: Icewind you are sort of correct indeed. I should have implemented equals and hashcode and then things would have worked out fine. Thanks for the assist, I'll count it as answered as I'm not getting a better answer anyway ;-)